# If I start a script using audostart where do my logs go?

Tags: python, boot, logfiles

I've added an entry to my `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file as follows:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash

@/usr/bin/python /home/pi/magicmirror-config/test-pir.py
```

My line is the last line.

I have added code to `test-pir.py` to write logs. I have used a non-relative path which is:

`/home/pi/magicmirror-config/logs`

**test-pir.py**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import logging

from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
  
if not os.path.exists("/home/pi/magicmirror-config/logs"):
    os.makedirs("/home/pi/magcimirror-config/logs")


formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler("logs/magicmirror-config.log", when="d", interval=1, backupCount=5)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(handler)   


logger.info("Script startup.")
```

If I run the file from the command like like this:

`python test-pir.py`

... I get my logs output to the specified folder no problem.

However, when the script runs as part of the auto start sequence no logs are written to the specified location.

The script runs, it reads a PIR sensor on GPIO to turn on a monitor, but I don't see any logs.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Showing the code of `/home/pi/magicmirror-config/test-pir.py` might help to analyze the problem.

Comment: *"I have used a non-relative path "* -> You create a directory with one, yes.  But I do not see a relationship between that and the handler passed to the logger, which **is relative**.  As a guess (I've never used LXDE's autostart), it may end up as `/home/pi/logs`.  However, it could instead be relative to `/`, which the pi user would not have permission to write to.

Comment: Just spotted exactly the same thing myself. Silly mistake... I should know better :)

Comment: your question belongs at a linux site ... it is not Raspberry Pi specific